# Using env variables in serverless s-resources-cf.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Is there a way to use serverless env variable in s-resources-cf.json?

I create a RDS instance in s-resources-cf.json that's used by some of my lambdas. Instead of putting the db name and password into s-project.json or s-variables-env.json I’d like to reference env vars and have them filled in as part of the deployment, similar to how vars in s-variables-env.json can be references in s-resources-cf.json using ${}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the ${rdsInstanceName} in the environment section of a function's `s-function.json` file, then access it using the `process.env.MyRdsInstanceName` within Lambda:

```
"environment": {
  "MyRdsInstanceName": "${rdsInstanceName}"
  ...
}
```

and reference this stage/region specific variable in your Lambda using something like:

```
var myRdsInstanceName = process.env.MyRdsInstanceName;
```

Hope this helps